# how to remove default xmlns entries when serializing a class

Tags: .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I've instantiated a class that is serializable, and I'm serializing it to a file, but it is always putting the following attributes in my root element:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

How can I stop that?

Answer (score 0):

This was alreayd asked on Stack Overflow

[Remove empty xmlns="" after Xml Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616328/remove-empty-xmlns-after-xml-serialization)